# SQL injection if brackets and semicolons are filtered

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I have a statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 123456
```

`123456` is provided by the user so it is vulnerable to SQLi but if I strip all semicolons and brackets, is it possible for the hacker to run any other statements (like `DROP,UPDATE,INSERT` etc) except `SELECT`?

I am already using prepared statements but I am curious that if the input is stripped of the line-terminator and brackets, can the hacker modify the DB in any way?

Comment: Why go through the worry? Just use prepared statements, or stored procedures, or whatever mechanism the platform you use provides. SQL injection is a **solved** problem. Don't make work and stress for yourself.

Comment: There's a nice page about that on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Semicolons aren't required statement delimiters. If they supply `123456 UPDATE FOO SET Bar = 12` that will work.

Comment: @ClickUpvote From the FAQ: `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.`. While I accept this is borderline, in that it is answerable, I think it is a) not a problem you face, and (b) is in reality very open-ended. Therefore, voting to close.

Comment: *can the hacker modify the DB in any way?* Even if the answer were no, you're exposing yourself to information theft, which can be just as bad. Think about creative UNION queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use sql parameters. Attempting to "sanitize" input is an **extremely** bad idea. Try googling some complex sql injection snippets, you won't believe how creative black hat hackers are.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's very difficult to be 100% certain that you are safe from this type of attack by trying to strip out specific characters - there are just too many ways to get around your code (by using character encodings etc.)

A better option is to pass parameters to a stored procedure, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MyStoredProcedure
    @MyParam  int
AS

BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = @MyParam

END
GO
```

That way SQL will treat the value passed in as a parameter, and nothing else, no matter what it contains.  And in this case it would only accept a value of type int anyway.

If you don't want, or can't, use a stored procedure, then I'd suggest changing your code so that the input parameter can only contain a pre-defined list of characters - in this case numeric characters.  That way you can be certain that the value is safe to use.

Comment: You don't have to use stored procs, you can use just parameterised queries.

Comment: I guess that's true, but if the input is coming from a user then I assumed that he was creating a dynamic sql statement and then passing it through to SQL server to execute, in which case a stored procedure would be (at least for me) the better option.